# Client Server MVC Architecture

Tags: user-interface, model-view-controller, client-server

I am looking to get some input with regards to the MVC design pattern when used in a client server application. I have seen some posts on this this which say that generally there are many ways you can implement MVC and Client Server, so I am wondering if the way I have implemented mine is acceptable/logical or not:

SERVER CLASS 
(controller) -----------> JDBC CLASS (model) -----------------> Database

```
|
|
V
```

GUI CLASSES 
  (view)

(Sorry for the terrible illustration. The GUI classes interact with the server back and forth, the server interacts with the JDBC back and forth, and the JDBC interacts with the database). There is no other communication between classes.)

The Server, JDBC and Database are all server side, and the GUI classes are client side. At the moment, each time a transaction is needed through a user interaction on the client side, a socket connection is established to connect to the server through which an object is sent. The server will then take the object and based on its parameters will call the relevant method from the JDBC class which will then pass the result back to the server class, which will then pass an object back to the GUI class which then updates its view.

Also, my controller does not have an instance of the view and an instance of the model created in it's constructor. One GUI class will simply call another one when a new frame is needed and it updates itself based on the response it gets back from the controller (I have often seen that the model should update the view, however in my case the model interacts with the controller/server class, which then communicates with the GUI classes over a socket, and the GUI classes then update themselves accordingly).

My main concern is whether this is an acceptable MVC architecture and also if it is ok to have the server class act as a controller between the model and the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfect, you are passing model to view through controller. I have one suggestion, I hope you are not putting all the business logic in controller, have one app service layer in between controller and model layer which will do data mesh from different models and return data to controller and the controller will return that object back to view. You can call returned object from controller as DTO(data transformation object). Make sure your controller is very thin just to control the calls between app service/model layer and view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the majority of my business logic is in the model. In the controller I just call various methods from within the model depending on the request that is received from the view. I am concerned that I have quite a bit of code in my view class for generating JComponents depending on the response from the controller, but I can't see any other way to update the view than by doing it from within the view class because the JComponents that need updating are all local to that class.